# Paperclip: No handler found for "application/javascript"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm trying to upload javascript files with paperclip and geting

```
No handler found for "application/javascript"
.../paperclip-3.2.0/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/registry.rb:19:in `handler_for'
.../paperclip-3.2.0/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/registry.rb:29:in `for'
.../paperclip-3.2.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:91:in `assign'
.../paperclip-3.2.0/lib/paperclip.rb:196:in `block in has_attached_file'
```

I am using this as part of a templating system. As part of my seed.rb (so I'm not uploading this via a form) I loop through files in a directory, create a new Javascript object for each one, set 'path', 'extension' and 'body' and then a callback sets the paperclip attachment named 'source' before validation and another attachment named 'preview' after save. The error is occurring in `compile_preview` at `self.preview = file`

models/javascript.rb

```
has_attached_file :source,
                :default_style => :original,
                :path => ":rails_root/tmp/:configured_path",
                :url => ":configured_url",
                :default_url   => "/assets/missing.gif",
                :use_timestamp => false,
                :storage => :filesystem

before_validation :set_source
before_post_process { false }
after_save :compile_preview

validates :body,          :presence => true,
                          :length   => { :maximum => 500.kilobytes }
validates :path,          :presence => true
validates :format,        :presence => true,
                          :inclusion => ["js"]
validates :handler,       :presence => true,
                          :inclusion => ["coffee", "js"]

def set_source
  file = StringIO.new(self.body)
  file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
  file.original_filename = "#{File.basename(self.path)}.#{self.extension}"
  file.content_type = "application/javascript"
  self.source = file
end

def compile_preview
  file = StringIO.new(self.render)
  file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
  file.original_filename = self.source_file_name
  file.content_type = self.source_content_type
  self.preview = file
  self.save
end
```

I know 99% of this works because I've used it with another model, but it's just "application/javascript" which is causing a problem. I've also tried "text/plain" and the old "text/javascript" mime type too but get the same error.

I see no mention of anyone having problems with handlers in this way before and paperclip has no mention of it.

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 & Paperclip 3.2.0

Could my `handler` attribute be conflicting with paperclip?

Does anyone have any insight into where I'm going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to take a break and look at it with fresh eyes.

I'd shortened the code above to explain it better, but this is what I actually had:

```
def rendered_source_file
  file = StringIO.new(self.render)   
  file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
  file.original_filename = self.source_file_name
  file.content_type = self.source_content_type
end

def compile_preview
  self.preview = rendered_source_file
  self.save
end
```

The issue was with `rendered_source_file`, I should be returning `file` not `file.content_type`.

So it should've been:

```
def rendered_source_file
  file = StringIO.new(self.render)   
  file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
  file.original_filename = self.source_file_name
  file.content_type = self.source_content_type
  file
end

def compile_preview
  self.preview = rendered_source_file
  self.save
end
```